# How can I order topics by post.date_written?

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables(I'm making kind of forum) I would like to sort topics order by last post that has been written(order by row 'posts.date_written'). I was trying to do it by myself but I couldn't get it working.

Topic table:

```
ID|id_subforum|owner_id|owner|title|description
```

Posts table:

```
ID|id_subforum|id_topic|by|description|date_written
```

Can somebody show me how should this SQL look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM topics AS t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_topic, id_subforum, MAX(date_written) AS last_date
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY id_topic, id_subforum
) AS p
ON t.id = p.id_topic AND t.id_subforum = p.id_subforum
WHERE t.id_subforum = '$forumId'
ORDER BY last_date DESC
```

Comment: On this moment I have SELECT * FROM subforum_name WHERE id='$forumId' How can I fit it to your sql

Comment: What is `subforum_name`? What does that have to do with my answer?

Comment: Yes sorry wrong sql, I mean this one: SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id_subforum='$forumId'

Comment: I'm getting Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\enigma\views\subforum\show_all_topics.php on line 49, php mysqli: $selectTopics = $db->query("SELECT t.*
FROM topics AS t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_topic, MAX(date_written) AS last_date
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY id_topic
) AS p
ON t.id = p.id_topic AND t.id_subforum = p.id_subforum
WHERE t.id_subforum = '$forumId'
ORDER BY last_date DESC");

Comment: I'm getting  Unknown column 'p.id_subforum' in 'on clause'

Comment: I was missing that from the subquery, fixed.